# Node.js with SSL/TLS protocol v1.2

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, tls, node.js

I would like to use TLS 1.2 on my node.js server.  I'm currently using openssl 1.0.0e.

If I upgrade to openssl 1.0.1, do I need to rebuild node.js to upgrade to TLS 1.2?  Are there configuration or build settings to specify which ciphers I want to use?

Also, after upgrading to TLS 1.2 would I need to generate new SSL certificates?

Comment: I think i'd probably just use stunnel to wrap connections ahead of node.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems that OpenSSL is fully backward compatible. I've updated OpenSSL till it was only 0.9.3 and hasn't any problems with certificates. 
OpenSSL has options to build with various crypt schemes, including proprietary/patented, so you can choose what you want.